# How to add a ternary operator in css in js with react spring

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-spring, css-in-js

I want my page transition to happen conditionally based on screen size. I don't want the animation to happen on small screens. This is what I've written:

```
const mq = window.matchMedia( "(min-width: 600px)" )

  const transitions = useTransition(location, location => location.pathname, {
    from: {{mq ? transform: "translateX(100%)" : transform: "translateX(0)"}, position:'absolute', width: '100vw', opacity: 0},
    enter: {opacity: 1, width: '100vw', transform: "translateX(0)"},
    leave: {opacity: 0, transform: "translateX(-50%)"}
  })
```

I've tried different variations of this but it doesn't work.

Comment: There is a syntax error with your curly braces.

Comment: whoops, that was a copy paste mistake. I edited the code. This is the syntax on my editor, which still gives me an error

Answer (score 1):

You were close. The property's key and value are technically expressions, so with that in mind you can have the ternary expression as the value. Having the whole thing as such is not valid syntax.

```
transform: mq? "translateX(100%)": "translateX(0)"
```

Comment: Even tidier - `transform: `translateX(${mq ? '100%' : '0'})`